# How to load .pst file into Outlook.Application?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I need to read a couple of pst files and extract attachments.

The code below is loading the default existing Outlook profile (in this case my Office Outlook profile).

```
      Outlook.Application OlApp = new Outlook.Application();
      OlApp.Session.AddStore(pstfile); // Loading c:\\ xyz.pst
      Outlook.Folders folders = OlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders;
      .........
      .....
      Outlook.MailItem mi = (Outlook.MailItem)itms[j];
      foreach (Outlook.Attachment attachment in mi.Attachments)
      {
          string fileName = attachment.FileName ?? attachment.DisplayName;
          string filePath = txtDestination.Text + "\\" + fileName;
                                            attachment.SaveAsFile(filePath);
       }
```

How to load pst files into `Outlook.Application` and loop those folders?

Answer (score 0):

After adding a new store to the profile, you can find your store in the [Stores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.stores) collection:

```
Outlook.Application OlApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.Namespace ns = OlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
ns.AddStore(pstfile); // Loading c:\\ xyz.pst
Outlook.Stores stores = ns.Stores;
Outlook.Folders folders = stores[stores.Count].Folders;
```